# php fox Fevent Advanced Event Plugin

Tags: php, events, phpfox

I use phpfox and have the fevents plugin.

How can I change the titles on the fevent events page, when I do custom fields it puts the title "custom fields", I want to change that working to Details.

I looked in phase manager and Theme css files and cannot find anywhere to change it.

How can I change that wording?

Here is the screen showing the wording I want to change:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the AdminCP and change the phrase from there. If the add-on is coded properly the phrases it uses will be found in the Phrase Manager